# problem finding marginal distribution for a PDF

Tags: probability-distributions

I need to find the marginal distribution function $f_y$ for
$$f_{xy}(u,v)=
\begin{cases}
1\over u,  & \text{$u\ge 1, 0\le v \le {1 \over u}$} \\
0, & \text{else}  \\
\end{cases}$$

my problem is with the domain $1<u< \infty$ for there is no convergence for the integral.

Comment: Why do you use $u,v$ for the variables and not $x,y$. Just notation, nothing false.

Comment: that's from a past test, and that's how the prof. wrote the question...

Comment: For any given $v$, $u$ goes from $1$ to $1/v$ not to $\infty$.

Comment: why? and then, when x goes to $\infty$ and when till the function's graph?

Comment: No, x (or u) depends on y (or v). You cannot let it go to $\infty$. Wait, I will try to write an answer

Comment: Do, you see what I mean? You can always draw a picture of the support of the function (not of the function itself!). That will help you to see, the range in which $u$ can vary for every given $v$.

Answer (score 1):

As usual, including the indicator functions in the densities makes the problems disappear... Here the joint density is
$$
f_{X,Y}(u,v)=\frac1u\cdot\mathbf 1_{0\lt v\lt1}\cdot\mathbf 1_{1\lt u\lt1/v},
$$
hence
$$
f_Y(v)=\int_\mathbb Rf_{X,Y}(u,v)\,\mathrm du,
$$
that is,
$$
f_Y(v)=\mathbf 1_{0\lt v\lt1}\int_\mathbb R\frac1u\,\mathbf 1_{1\lt u\lt1/v}\,\mathrm du=\mathbf 1_{0\lt v\lt1}\int_1^{1/v}\frac1u\,\mathrm du=-\log v\cdot\mathbf 1_{0\lt v\lt1}.
$$